# Vertical scroll bar appears only in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, scrollbar, overflow

I built a site and local file works fine. The page mysteriously appears vertical scroll bar only in Chrome. Firefox and IE works fine. Very confused. It would be great if someone can help.
The site is here [problem site](http://h-a-s-h-t-a-g.com/)
if you hover to right hand image slide area, chrome will show vertical scroll bar which is not supposed to show.

Comment: Without examining the whole site, and what you are trying to do, have you tried adding `overflow-y: hidden` to your `#rightcontent` element?

Comment: Thanks. But actually I mean the scroll bar of body element. The design is not to have a overall vertical scroll bar in full screen, only to use 3 individual scroll bar of each 3 columns. It works fin either in local or when checking online using Firefox and IE, But Chrome always gives a vertical scroll bar when I hover to the very right column.

Comment: OK. I used other PC. It seems working fine. Maybe something wrong with my own Chrome???

Comment: yeap, the problem is with Google Chrome. try to open Chrome in other PCs or another user on your local pc. and check if the problem remains. and I guest it's GONE.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting a fixed width and height on your `#pagewrap` which is making your page have both vertical and horizontal scrolling because the content is bigger than the screen.

Try setting your `body` and `html` to `width: 100%; height: 100%;` and then for each of your columns, set the `width` to a percent, which should total up to 100%. Then, set the `height` of all of your columns to 100% and add `overflow: auto;`

Here's a fiddle of it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/v691zLfb/